# Dataset populated as null if filter criteria expanded from 10 days to whole month. OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, dataset

When i am filling dataset for upto 1 million rows from SQL Server 2012 everything is working fine. but when i reduce filter criteria and selecting around 3 million rows into dataset from sql server i am getting Dataset object as null

```
public DataSet ExecDataSet(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    return ExecDataSet(cmd);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lastErrorMsg = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: debug, set a breakpoint at `catch` and post the exception message

Comment: `ExecDataSet(cmd)`??? Is it a overload which accepts a command parameter?

Comment: i think i should try it by extending Commandtimeout. Sorry guys

Comment: It is actually a outofmemory exception. at Dataadapter.Fill(dataset).

Answer (score 0):

From your post description it looks like the query for fetching 3M rows is timing out due the code statement `cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;` and due to which it's throwing `Timeout` exception and it's reaching to `Catch()` block where you are returning `null` as can be seen below

```
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lastErrorMsg = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
```

Try increasing the timeout value and see if it successes.